# Windows reboot to safemode from command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, safe-mode

Im just wondering if there is a way to reboot the windows machine in safemode from command prompt.
 Looked at the man page of `shutdown` but it is not there.

Comment: Tools like "Teamviewer" does this.

Comment: A "man page" for Shutdown? On Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Vista and later, the command

```
 bcdedit /set safeboot Minimal
```

will enable safe mode (of course you must run this from an administrative command prompt) and the command

```
 bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot
```

will turn it off again.

Comment: Thanks.Something new to me,but need to have a generic solution.

Comment: Generic in what sense?  There is no solution that will work on all versions of Windows, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes thats what i mean,Something like editing a registry key or so.

Comment: There is no single solution that works for all versions of Windows.  You need to figure out which version of Windows is running and use the appropriate solution.  The solution Nicholas posted will work for versions prior to Vista, my solution will work for Vista and later.

Comment: so the editing via bcdedit is permament? That is, if you don't turn it off, the computer will keep booting into safe mode?

Comment: @shurane: I believe so.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a built-in command line method. You could in theory write one that sets the boot.ini flag and reboots the machine, though.

Comment: Could you flesh this out with an example of the boot.ini flag?